# Helm Chart. How to pass a env value with multiple dots?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

In deployment.yaml contains the condition:

```
          {{- if or $.Values.env $.Values.envSecrets }}
          env:
            {{- range $key, $value := $.Values.env }}
            - name: {{ $key }}
              value: {{ $value | quote }}
            {{- end }}
            {{- range $key, $secret := $.Values.envSecrets }}
            - name: {{ $key }}
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ $secret }}
                  key: {{ $key | quote }}
            {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
```

If I pass the $key = `helm install NAME nexus/stand --set env.server.servlet.context-path=/bpm/router-app`, then i don't get what i expect:

```
Containers:

...

    Environment:
      server:   map[servlet:map[context-path:/bpm/router-app]]
```

How can I get around this problem and get the environment like:

```
    Environment:
      server.servlet.context-path:   /bpm/router-app
```

Comment: Which Kubernetes and helm versions are you using? "If I pass the $key = `helm install NAME nexus/stand --set env.server.servlet.context-path=/bpm/router-app`" - what do you mean exactly? How do you passing it? Could you add more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double backslashes.

```
helm install NAME nexus/stand --set env.server\\.servlet\\.context-path=/bpm/router-app
```

That is the equivalent of:

```yaml
env:
  server.servlet.context-path: /bpm/router-app
```

This is useful particularly for annotations.

Alternatively you should be able to use quotes and single backslashes.

```
helm install NAME nexus/stand --set 'env.server\.servlet\.context-path'=/bpm/router-app
```

Comment: Could you mark as solution? Thanks.

Comment: Can't find how to mark it resolved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Should be a tick under the vote count in the answer.